# derive highest and lowest numbers without a list in python

Tags: python, input

I am tasked with returning high and low numbers from inputs. I am restricted from using lists or importing functions. this is what I have:
The suggestion below failed. I suspect something is amiss in my code:

I added this:

[image]

My return was this:

[image]

Comment: If one is not the oldest, that means he is the youngest?

Comment: not necessarily. the list could be infinite, but most inputs consist of 4 numbers.

Comment: Your indentation seems to be off. Can you fix that?

Comment: I see that my indents are off again. Disregard.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the conditionals inside the loop and not outside. This code will get you the oldest and youngest.

```
oldest = -1
youngest = 1000
for i in range(ppl):
     age = int(input("Age of Person: " + str(i+1) + ": "))
     total += age
     if age > oldest:
         oldest = age
     if age < youngest:
         youngest = age

print("Average age is:", total / ppl)
print("Oldest age is: ", oldest)
print("Youngest age is:", youngest)
```

Comment: Thank you. forgive my ignorance. what does setting oldest and youngest to -1 and 1000 do?

Comment: It initialises the values to (something) outside a plausible range.

Comment: excellent. makes perfect sense. thank you